# How to make a particular instance of a sprite pause for some time andengine

Tags: sprite, andengine

I have a sprite whose numerous instances are on the scene at a particular point of time. Is it possible to make one particular instance pause on the screen for an instance. I know i have to do it with a thread wait (probably) but when i try to wait on a particular sprite instance, it pauses the whole scene for the time that i specified which is not what i want. Can someone help?

This is the code

```
    if((_target.contains(P4X[5], P4Y[5])) || (_target.contains(P5X[4], P5Y[4]))){

                removeSprite(_target);

     }
```

I want to wait here for some time and then remove the sprite _target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two tools you will need are

```
// will make your sprite stop updting.
sprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
```

And use as TimerHandler to reactivate the sprite when done.

```
//TimerHandler(seconds, autoReset, callback)
TimerHandler timerHandler = new TimerHandler(0.1f, true, new ITimerCallback(){
@Override
public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler arg0) {
     // Called when timer has completed
     // unpause your sprite here.
}
});
scene.registerUpdateHandler(timerHandler);
```

These two tools should let you pause and unpause a sprite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DelayModifier:

```
DelayModifier mod = new DelayModifier(numberOfSeconds);
mod.addModifierListener(new IModifierListener<IEntity>() {

    @Override
    public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
        removeSprite(_target);

    }
});
_target.registerEntityModifier(mod);
```